# Get Line Number From Caret

Tags: c++, windows-8, textbox, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I'm trying to get the line number from the carets position in a textbox, here is what I have:

```
int Editor::GetLineFromCaret(const std::wstring &text)
{
    unsigned int lineCount = 1;

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i <= m_editWindow->SelectionStart; ++i)
    {
        if(text[i] == '\n')
        {
            ++lineCount;
        }
    }

    return lineCount;
}
```

But i'm getting some weird errors. Example, if I have 10 lines of text in a textbox and use this function it wont give me the correct line number unless the caret is about 10 characters into the line and some lines will have no characters so it will be incorrect.

This is how I solved the problem with help from Damir Arh:

```
int Editor::GetLineFromCaret(const std::wstring &text)
{
    unsigned int lineCount = 1;
    unsigned int selectionStart = m_editWindow->SelectionStart;

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i <= selectionStart; ++i)
    {
        if(text[i] == '\n')
        {
            ++lineCount;
            ++selectionStart;
        }
    }

    return lineCount;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your calculation doesn't work because a new line takes up two characters in the string (`\r\n`) but the `SelectionStart` value counts a new line only as a single character. As a result after each new line you are 1 character off, i.e. you need to move one character further into the line before you detect the correct line.

To fix the calculation you need to take `\r` characters into account:

```
int Editor::GetLineFromCaret(const std::wstring &text)
{
    unsigned int lineCount = 1;
    unsigned int selectionStart = m_editWindow->SelectionStart;

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i <= m_editWindow->SelectionStart; ++i)
    {
        if(text[i] == '\n')
        {
            ++lineCount;
        }
        if(text[i] == '\r')
        {
            ++selectionStart;
        }
    }

    return lineCount;
}
```

Comment: Your lineCount is off by one when I go back to a previous line. I'll mark your answer as correct because you helped me figure out what the problem was. I didn't have to take '\r' into account. I updated my question with the answer.